# Getting text in span

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

HTML code:

```
span class="_2VF2J19pUIMSLJFky-7PEI" data-testid="post_timestamp" data-click-id="timestamp" style="color: rgb(129, 131, 132);">8 months ago</span
```

I want to extract "8 months ago".
I code I am using is not giving any result.

```
data.find_all('span', attrs={'data-testid': True,'data-click-id' : True,'color':True})
```

Comment: `color` is not an attribute, `style` is. You can't really match on CSS selectors using BS, but you could do a regex match on the string `color:` inside the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches - Select element by an exact attributes value:

```
soup.select_one('[data-testid="post_timestamp"]').text
```

by a containing text `ago` if it is lways available:

```
soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("ago")').text
```

by color in style attribute:

```
soup.select_one('span[style*="color"]').text
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<span class="_2VF2J19pUIMSLJFky-7PEI" data-testid="post_timestamp" data-click-id="timestamp" style="color: rgb(129, 131, 132);">8 months ago</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.select_one('[data-testid="post_timestamp"]').text
#soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("ago")').text
#soup.select_one('span[style*="color"]').text
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are only saying *give me an element that has these attributes*, which might give you more elements than you'd like. But you could also say *give me an element that has an attribute with this value*.

The `data-testid="post_timestamp"` attribute could come in handy to identify the span, as it seems that it identifies the timestamp of the post.

```py
data.find_all('span', attrs={'data-testid': 'post_timestamp'})
```

Now you are telling BeautifulSoup to return a `<span>` with `data-testid="post_timestamp"`, which should match the element you want.

If you want to find a single element instead of multiple, you can also use `data.find` instead of `data.find_all`. `data.find` basically returns you only the first element of `data.find_all`.

You can get the text of the element by accessing the `text` property of an element.

```py
timestamp_element = data.find("span", {"data-testid": "post_timestamp"})
text = timestamp_element.text
```